# How to Customize Base Components?

Tags: lwc-oss

I want to use a custom icon with a button. The standard [lightning-button](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/example) could not be used because it does not support custom icons. So I looked into the [base-components-recipes](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes) repository as the docs suggest. How do I actually customize the `button` component? Do I need to deploy all the components from the [lwc](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc) folder into my org? My concerns is you need to deploy the whole slew of other components that I don't need.

Comment: Why not just create your own button using native HTML Components?

Comment: That's a good option as well. Thank you for you suggestion, @glls. Yet I am still curious to know how to customize base components.

Comment: Base components are very limited (other than the options given which are usually documented) if you need to modify the styling or functionality, you are almost always better off creating your own using HTML components

Comment: Yes, base components in the `lighning` namespace are limited. But they are open-sources in [base-components-recipes](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes) which means a developer can create the same `lightning-button` with customizations. My question is about using this open source repo.

Comment: ahhhh, i see what you mean. Edited the tag(s). In any case, unless you submit a pull request to the repo and modify the base component's code, the same principles apply using lwc-oss, if its not an option, you cant change it and you are better off creating your own component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to deploy everything that they've provided that is required for the actual component you're interested in

- The actual base component
- Dependencies specific to that base component (labels, other LWCs, utils)

Most examples/tutorials naturally just have you push the whole repository, but you'll have to do some work to figure out the exact dependencies that are actually needed to support the one component you're interested in.